# How to prevent attacks to server

Tags: attacks, firewalls, centos

I have 3 CentOS server configured for my applications. Recently I recognized that there is so many attacks to my servers. I have so many logs about attempt to login to my servers using sshd from unknown IPs.

This is some part of my secure log:

```
May 25 03:45:03 mail sshd[22291]: Invalid user user from 42.121.117.150
May 25 03:45:03 mail sshd[22303]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user
May 25 03:45:03 mail sshd[22291]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
May 25 03:45:03 mail sshd[22291]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=42.121.117.150 
May 25 03:45:03 mail sshd[22291]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): error retrieving information about user user
May 25 03:45:05 mail sshd[22291]: Failed password for invalid user user from 42.121.117.150 port 59430 ssh2
May 25 03:45:05 mail sshd[22303]: Received disconnect from 42.121.117.150: 11: Bye Bye
May 25 03:45:07 mail sshd[22563]: Invalid user user from 42.121.117.150
May 25 03:45:07 mail sshd[22564]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user
May 25 03:45:07 mail sshd[22563]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
May 25 03:45:07 mail sshd[22563]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=42.121.117.150 
May 25 03:45:07 mail sshd[22563]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): error retrieving information about user user
May 25 03:45:09 mail sshd[22563]: Failed password for invalid user user from 42.121.117.150 port 59655 ssh2
May 25 03:45:09 mail sshd[22564]: Received disconnect from 42.121.117.150: 11: Bye Bye
May 25 03:45:11 mail sshd[22565]: Invalid user user1 from 42.121.117.150
May 25 03:45:11 mail sshd[22566]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user1
May 25 03:45:11 mail sshd[22565]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
May 25 03:45:11 mail sshd[22565]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=42.121.117.150 
May 25 03:45:11 mail sshd[22565]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): error retrieving information about user user1
May 25 03:45:13 mail sshd[22565]: Failed password for invalid user user1 from 42.121.117.150 port 59861 ssh2
May 25 03:45:13 mail sshd[22566]: Received disconnect from 42.121.117.150: 11: Bye Bye
May 25 03:45:15 mail sshd[22570]: Invalid user user from 42.121.117.150
May 25 03:45:15 mail sshd[22571]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user
May 25 03:45:15 mail sshd[22570]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
May 25 03:45:15 mail sshd[22570]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=42.121.117.150 
May 25 03:45:15 mail sshd[22570]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): error retrieving information about user user
May 25 03:45:17 mail sshd[22570]: Failed password for invalid user user from 42.121.117.150 port 60107 ssh2

...

May 30 05:28:20 mail sshd[29998]: Failed password for root from 219.138.135.68 port 45105 ssh2
May 30 05:28:21 mail sshd[30273]: Failed password for root from 219.138.135.68 port 53227 ssh2
May 30 05:28:21 mail sshd[30266]: Failed password for root from 219.138.135.68 port 51786 ssh2
May 30 05:28:21 mail unix_chkpwd[30296]: password check failed for user (root)
May 30 05:28:21 mail unix_chkpwd[30297]: password check failed for user (root)
May 30 05:28:21 mail sshd[30280]: Failed password for root from 219.138.135.68 port 55313 ssh2
May 30 05:28:22 mail unix_chkpwd[30298]: password check failed for user (root)

...

May 31 11:12:38 mail sshd[2461]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=211.233.60.37  user=root
May 31 11:12:40 mail sshd[2461]: Failed password for root from 211.233.60.37 port 48375 ssh2
May 31 11:12:40 mail sshd[2462]: Received disconnect from 211.233.60.37: 11: Bye Bye
May 31 11:12:45 mail unix_chkpwd[2671]: password check failed for user (root)
May 31 11:12:45 mail sshd[2669]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=211.233.60.37  user=root
May 31 11:12:47 mail sshd[2669]: Failed password for root from 211.233.60.37 port 48619 ssh2
May 31 11:12:47 mail sshd[2670]: Received disconnect from 211.233.60.37: 11: Bye Bye
May 31 11:12:50 mail unix_chkpwd[2675]: password check failed for user (root)
May 31 11:12:50 mail sshd[2673]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=211.233.60.37  user=root
May 31 11:12:52 mail sshd[2673]: Failed password for root from 211.233.60.37 port 48905 ssh2
May 31 11:12:53 mail sshd[2674]: Received disconnect from 211.233.60.37: 11: Bye Bye
...
```

How can I block this kind of attacks to my server? I have iptables installed on my server and all ports (except my needs) are rejected inside it.

Comment: Not aware of your network set-up but is there a need to have sshd open to public ? Is there any firewall involved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would install [sshguard](http://sshguard.sourceforge.net) on this server to automatically block hosts trying to bruteforce your ssh accounts. It does this by adding the offending hosts to the firewall rules.

An alternative to this is [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) which do more or less the same as sshguard, but uses /etc/hosts.deny instead of firewall rules to block the offenders.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @DogEatCatWorld's answer, there is a more general piece of software called '[fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)' that can be configured to monitor log files for specific regular expressions and track IP addresses that act 'suspiciously' (for instance, multiple failed ssh login attempts within a certain timespan) and temporarily block the IP address at the firewall level.

It comes with a number of default rulesets for most common daemons and is almost infinitely tweakable if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could (should ?) also :

- disable ssh root login (You can still use sudo to do system administration)
- Disable password authentication and enable key authentication